# Why am I getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" after refactoring my code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I have a table which has a few columns, one of which is an FK ID of the "owner".

In my delete statement, I have the following code:

```
public ActionResult DeleteEmailTemplate(int id = 0)
{
    EmailTemplate EmailTemplate = db.EmailTemplates.Find(id);

    Company _Company = SelectCompany();

    if (_Company.id != EmailTemplate.CompanyID.id)
        return Content("Security Error");

    return Content("Passed... Do Delete stuff");
 }
```

That works fine, but, I need to do this in many places, so I tried to extract the method and I now have:

```
public ActionResult DeleteEmailTemplate(int id = 0)
{
    EmailTemplate EmailTemplate = db.EmailTemplates.Find(id);

    if (!SecurityCheck(EmailTemplate.CompanyID.id))
         return Content("Security Fail");

    return Content("Passed... Do Delete stuff");    
}
```

I think the code for `SecurityCheck` is not relevant as I have been setting breakpoints and I know that the error is because when `SecurityCheck` is called, `EmailTemplate.CompanyID` is Null, but... I can't work out why it is Null.

In the first example, it is Null, but the moment I do `SelectCompany()` and check `EmailTemplate`, `EmailTemplate.CompanyID` is set to the correct value, despite this method only populates the `_Company` object and does not touch anything else.

In the second example, it is Null again but stays null.

So, the  problems are that I need help with:

I can't figure out why it is Null to begin with when the database has the correct ID.

I can't figure out why it is getting the correct value in the first example after running `SelectCompany()`.

And most importantly, what do I need to do to fix it?, I am guessing I have messed up somewhere big, but I just don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't figure out why it is Null to
>   begin with when the database has the
>   correct ID.

This line ...

```
EmailTemplate EmailTemplate = db.EmailTemplates.Find(id);
```

... would never load a navigation property (`CompanyID` in your case). Navigation properties are only eager loaded (with `Include`), explicitely loaded or lazily loaded. You don't seem to have lazy loading enabled, otherwise accessing `CompanyID` should load the property automatically. And you don't make use of the other two options.

> I can't figure out why it is getting
>   the correct value in the first example
>   after running SelectCompany().

Probably because of relationship span. When you load the company into the context in your `SelectCompany` method, Entity Framework fixes automatically references in other objects which are already loaded. For this reason `EmailTemplate.CompanyID` gets populated automatically.

> And most importantly, what do I need
>   to do to fix it?,

Use one of the three options mentioned above:

Eager loading (one round trip):

```
EmailTemplate EmailTemplate = db.EmailTemplates.Include(e => e.CompanyID)
    .Where(e => e.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();
```

Explicit loading (two round trips):

```
EmailTemplate EmailTemplate = db.EmailTemplates.Find(id);
db.Entry(EmailTemplate).Reference(e => e.CompanyID).Load();
```

Or enable lazy loading.

(In your special case I'd prefer eager loading.)

Comment: Suddenly Entity Framework seems to get a lot more complicated and complex than I first though / from the examples! Still liking it though!.... Will be trying out your solution soon and will mark if/when it works. Thanks.

Comment: Ok... Confirmed both work - Gone for the second for now as I understand the syntax and I am trying to learn at the moment... I understand the other one is better and will switch to that when I understand more as it is going over my head slightly at the moment.... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectCompany` must be exercising some code that populates `CompanyID`. My guess is you are using an ORM with lazy loading and SelectCompany causes the CompanyID to get populated.